# RT5390 Wifi Adapter not found Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers

I know that the question is alreadz posted but unfortunately I can't find an answer that works for me. 
I have since a lot of distros the problem that my wifi doesn't work, but till now I got it workin with the following code:

```
cd /home/makkekkazzo/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rt5390sta
sudo ifconfig enp2s0 up
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But I installed yesterday Bionic Beaver and the solution doesn't work anymore.

Now when I do `sudo make` it says at a certain point

```
In function 'memcpy',
inlined from 'rt_ioctl_iwaplist' at /home/makkekkazzo/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c:694:2:
./include/linux/string.h:340:4: error: call to '__read_overflow2' declared with attribute error: detected read beyond size of object passed as 2nd parameter
__read_overflow2();
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And the next is the result for `sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7d00000-f7d0ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 30:85:a9:2e:0f:f0
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7c00000-f7c3ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s20u2
       serial: d6:ee:db:46:b1:1d
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.169 link=yes multicast=yes
```

As said I've tried different solutions but I did not get anywhere.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please include where you are getting the source code that is being built.

Comment: I think I found the code you were using. From what I can tell the Linux kernel changed some functionality around 4.13 which is why the compilation fails now. Here is a [patch](https://github.com/agerwick/RT28XX-RT539X-Linux-driver/pull/11/files) that fixes that specific driver. You can download the [already patched version](https://github.com/alexbeloi/RT28XX-RT539X-Linux-driver) or [download the patch](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/agerwick/RT28XX-RT539X-Linux-driver/pull/11.patch) and run `git apply < name_of_file.patch`

Comment: Hi Kristopher, thanks a lot, you were right. That was the problem. Unfortunately now the computer freezes in the moment it gets connected to WLAN. Do you know why?

Comment: It's either the timer code that changed causing it to crash or the new memcpy code. You could try reverting to the original version and only applying the memcpy part of the patch. You also might want to look at `dmesg` or other system logs to see what is causing the panic.

Comment: @KristopherIves: I posted the results of `dmesg` in [an other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105637/computer-freezes-when-connected-to-wifi) but I don't know what how to repair the problem. Thanks for the help